# Update checked state of checkbox in table header on page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table with a checkbox at the top of the first column to allow the user to select all items in the table and perform an AJAX script. I'm using PHP to generate the html table from a database query - I'd like to set the checked value for the header checkbox if all items in the table are also checked for the same column.

In the PHP file I'm setting up the table and the header rows first, then doing a `foreach` loop to create the table rows from the found records. I could add a counter along the way to track how many rows are checked, but as this is happening after the table header I can't see a way to subsequently update the header row? Unless this could be done via Javascript?

Here's my PHP page that generates the table:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
   <thead>
     <th><input type="checkbox" class="select-all checkbox" name="select-all" />    </th>
     <th class="text-center" scope="col">Product ID</th>
     <th class="text-center" scope="col">Description</th>
   </thead>
<tbody>

  $found = $result->getFoundSetCount();

  foreach($records as $record) {

        $productID = $record->getField('productID');

        if (!in_array($productID, $_SESSION['selectedProductIDs'])) {
            $checked = '';
        } else {
            $checked = ' checked';
        }

        ?>
        <tr class="" id="<?php echo $recid ?>">
            <td id="<?php echo $productID; ?>"><input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="<?php echo $productID; ?>" <?php echo $checked; ?>></td>
            <td><?php echo $productID; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $record->getField('Description'); ?></td>
        </tr>                                   

} // foreach
```

Comment: There is no way of going back. You need to check for the state of all checkboxes prior to the generation of `thead`.

Comment: So what you want is - `if you click on the header checkbox all the checkbox should check.??`

Answer (score 0):

> i did not test this code, but i think is what do you search

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    var allAreChecked = true;
    $("table > tbody > tr > td > input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
        if(! $(this).is(':checked'))
            allAreChecked = false;
    });

    if(allAreChecked === true){
        $("table > thead > tr > th > input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', true);
    }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple do the trick with `string concatenation` like below

**1st :** First run the `foreach` loop and `concatenate` all `tr` as a string .

**2nd :** Outside the `foreach` loop Set the `$check_all_button=true;` in foreach loop  check any row is `not` `checked` means set the variable to `false`.

**3rd :** After all this concatenate the table header part with another variable . based on  `$check_all_button` variable value check the checkbox .

**4th :** Finally echo the both variables . to render the html table .

```
<?php

    $found = $result->getFoundSetCount();
    $table_tr='';
    $check_all_button=true;
    foreach($records as $record) 
    {

        $productID = $record->getField('productID');

        if (!in_array($productID, $_SESSION['selectedProductIDs'])) {
            $checked = '';

            $check_all_button=false;

        } else {
            $checked = ' checked';
        }


       $table_tr.="<tr class='' id='<?php echo $recid ?>'>
            <td id='<?php echo $productID; ?>'><input type='checkbox' class='select-item checkbox' name='select-item' value='<?php echo $productID; ?>' <?php echo $checked; ?>></td>
            <td><?php echo $productID; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $record->getField('Description'); ?></td></tr> ";


    <?php

    } 

    $check_all_button=true;
    $table_and_head='';

    $table_and_head.="<table class='table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered'>
                           <thead>
                             <th><input type='checkbox' class='select-all checkbox' name='select-all'";
                               if($check_all_button==true){   $table_and_head.=' checked'; }
             $table_and_head.=" />    </th>
                             <th class='text-center' scope='col'>Product ID</th>
                             <th class='text-center' scope='col'>Description</th>
                           </thead>
                        <tbody> </tbody> </table>";

    echo $table_and_head;
    echo $table_tr;

    ?>
```